# How could I print connected parts from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

How could I print which rooms are connected to the "de Lobby"? The things I tried returned string erros or other errors.

```
kamers = {

    1 : {  "naam"  : "de Lobby" ,
           "trap"  : 2,
           "gangrechtdoor" : 3 }  ,

    2 : {  "naam"  : "de Trap" ,
           "lobby"  : 1,
           "note"  : "Terwijl je de trap oploopt hoor je in de verte Henk van Ommen schreeuwen" }  ,            

    3 : {  "naam"  : "de Gang rechtdoor" ,
           "lobby" : 1,
           "gymzaal" : 4, 
           "concergie"  : 5,
           "gangaula"  : 6 } ,
```

This prints where you are, but as you can see, not which rooms are connected.

```
    print("Hier ben je: " + kamers[currentKamer]["naam"])
    print("hier kan je naartoe: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
kamers = {

    1: {"naam": "de Lobby",
        "trap": 2,
        "gangrechtdoor": 3},

    2: {"naam": "de Trap",
        "lobby": 1,
        "note": "Terwijl je de trap oploopt hoor je in de verte Henk van Ommen schreeuwen"},

    3: {"naam": "de Gang rechtdoor",
        "lobby": 1,
        "gymzaal": 4,
        "concergie": 5,
        "gangaula": 6}}

def find_connected_rooms(room_name, rooms):
    room_number = next(room_number for room_number, props in rooms.items() if props['naam'] == room_name)

    for room_props in rooms.values():
        if room_number in room_props.values():
            yield room_props['naam']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for connected_room in find_connected_rooms('de Lobby', kamers):
        print(connected_room)
```

**Output**

```
de Trap
de Gang rechtdoor
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is not quite clear but I assume you are looking for the items which has lobby key or any key with 1 as value

kamers[1] is lobby and it is "naam" is "de Lobby".

so This gets by if items inside has value 1 (Lobby's key)

```
[i for i in kamers.values() if 1 in i.values()]
```

or you can check if the key 'lobby' exists

```
[i for i in kamers.values() if i.get('lobby',None) ]
```

to get the name of the rooms you can replace for "i" with i['naam']

```
[i['naam'] for i in kamers.values() if i.get('lobby',None) ]
```

which returns

```
['de Trap', 'de Gang rechtdoor']
```

Comment: This answer it indeed, could I do, "[i['naam'] for i in kamers.values() if i.get('currentKamer',None) ]. Because I have a set variable which is currenKamer = 1 and everytime you move around it updates this variable.

Comment: If you want to check the currentKamer yes, it will work and also you can add  "and" after checking it has link to lobby.